# Ruby on Rails Better Way to Perform Select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have code like this to get only product that has been favourited by user.

```
@products = current_user.products.select {|product| product.count_favourited > 0 }
```

This code will use a big amount of memory if user has huge number of products. The problem is, I can't perform filtering on query because the number of users who have favourited the product is stored on Redis.

Someting like

```
def count_favourited
  $redis.scard("some_key_based_on_product_id")
end
```

Is there any other way to achieve this?

What about using `find_each` so internally it will use batch processing?

```
@products = []
current_user.products.find_each do |product|
  @products << product if product.count_favourited > 0
end
```

Comment: Why not write to db? It ll be much faster especially with bigger data set.

Comment: What to be written?, did you mean the number of favourited user?. Classic answer, it is legacy code hahaa.

Comment: just for your question `What to be written?` :  create a new table users_products with A `has_many :through association`. I'm sure you know this solution, but please tell me why you haven't choosen it ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
current_user.products.where("products.count_favourited > 0")
```

or use a scope:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base 
  scope :favourited, -> { where("count_favourited > 0") }
end

current_user.products.favourited
```

Am I missing something or is it just this simple?

Comment: Yes, you missed something. The number of user that favourited the product stored in Redis.

Comment: Why do you store just this number inside of redis and not in the db?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I don't know much about redis, but if your main concern is memory usage, two ideas come to mind. First, if I'm inferring correctly that you're using a Set within redis, then [sscan](http://redis.io/commands/sscan) may be helpful. As for a Rails solution:

```
@products = current_user.products.keep_if {|product| product.count_favourited > 0 }
```

If `current_user.products` returns a copy of the product list, then it should be safe to do an in-place modification of said copy. `keep_if` will do just that, thereby avoid the time and memory involved in making an additional copy for select (at the expense of the time required for an in-place operation, of course).

Answer (score 0):

> What about using find_each so internally it will use batch processing?

Yes, if you are only concerned about memory usage (not execution speed), then batch processing will solve your problem. Reducing memory usage is exactly what it was made for (and it doesn't give any other benefit).

Can you do it the other way around? I.e., ask redis to give you the product IDs that were liked by the user? I think I can guess the answer...